# Apache running but saying it's failed [CentOS 8 Stream]

Tags: apache-2.4, centos8

On a clean install of CentOS 8 Stream I run the following commands

```
yum install httpd -y  
yum install mod_ssl -y  
httpd -k start  
systemctl enable httpd
```

At this point Apache is running and pages are being served, but if I execute `systemctl status httpd` it will show me the following:
[image: screenshot]

Does anybody have any idea what is happening?

Apache version is 2.4.37 and there are no errors in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You manually launch the webserver with `httpd -k start` rather than with the systemd service unit and `systemctl start httpd` .

That means that Apache httpd is running, but not as a service managed by systemd and `systemctl status httpd`  can't effectively determine what's happening there.

Doing  `httpd -k start` breaks for instance the systemd `PrivateTmp` setting

Comment: Thank you very much!